# How can I overwrite the memory when binary reading finishes?

Tags: c, security, memory-management, dump, coredump

There is an open source project called [obash](https://github.com/louigi600/obash) which allows to encrypt Bash scripts with AES-256-CBC using OpenSSL. This project has some bugs. If we get the core dump of a running binary, we can get the source code, which defeats the purpose of encryption.

I contacted [the developer of this project](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6049292/louigi600) and he said he can't help because he had no time (I totally understand). I was able to create a binary on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS without this error, but I can't right now and I don't know why. According to [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/chat), it is possible to hide the source code with overwriting the memory with encrypted text. How can I do that?

Although effectively unmaintained, `obash` looks more sophisticated than e.g. `shc` which is known to be easy to circumvent. I am ultimately looking for a solution which allows me to distribute a Bash script in compiled form *without* the well-known vulnerabilities of `shc` et al. But this question simply concerns the immediate solution to the problem stated above.

Comment: Take a look to shc command.

Comment: @ulix The author of obash mentions a few reasons why shc doesn't cut it in the _"WHY this project"_ section of the README.

Comment: @ulix shc is pretty easy to crack the source code.

Comment: Relying on chatGPT for technical advice is ... ill-advised.

Comment: @tripleee Yes but after thinking, It looks kinda right.

Answer (score 0):

Obash actually uses source files, but after source file, the files are deleted, so the source code can be obtained by continuously copying /tmp files. I developed [shellc](https://github.com/chenzhch/shellc) to protect the source code and prevent debugging through `pipe sh` and `ptrace`.